# Method return values

Tags: objective-c

Objective C docs from apple says

> For the object-oriented constructs of
>   Objective-C, such as method return
>   values, id replaces int as the default
>   data type. (For strictly C constructs,
>   such as function return values, int
>   remains the default type.)

I thought the return type and hence value is something predefined in method signature. So could you give me some example on what the doc refers to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That line simply means that a method written as such, would, by default, return `id`:

```
- init { ... }
```

or

```
+ array { ... }
```

versus

```
- (id)init { ... }
```

---

In addition, a method written without explicit parameter types will take in `id` objects.

```
- initWithObject:object { ... }
```

is the same as

```
- (id)initWithObject:(id)object { ... }
```

Comment: Yep, though I heartily recommend leaving those specifiers in there. It's always better to be explicit and readable than not...